# no se envían los datos del formulario

Tags: nodejs, angular, backend

Estoy tratando de enviar el formulario a backend por medio del método POST, pero resulta que no se envían, no sé por qué razón. Reviso la consola del navegador en la pestaña red y no se ejecuta tan si quiera el método POST y mucho menos se envían los parámetros.

¿Alguna idea de qué puedo estar haciendo mal? Cabe destacar que lo que estoy tratando de hacer es el envío del formulario a mi correo y eso ya lo logré pero no he podido traer el valor de los campos del formulario al backend para insertarlos en el correo.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';

import swal from 'sweetalert';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.component.css']
})

export class ContactoComponent {
  constructor(public _MessageService: MessageService) {
  }

  contactForm(form) {
    this._MessageService.sendMessage(form).subscribe(() => {
    swal('Formulario de Contacto', 'Mensaje Enviado Correctamente', 'success');
   });
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" id="contenedor-padre"> 
    <img src="assets\img\imagen-conacto.jpg" alt="imagen de fondo" id="imagen-fondo">

    <div class="row" id="fila-movil">
        <div class="col-12" id="columna" >
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="contenedor-imagen-movil"> <img src="assets\img\imagen-contacto.jpg" class="img-rounded" id="imagen-movil" alt="Cinque Terre"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-4" id="fila">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-7" id="columna-izquierda">
          <div id="contenedor-formulario">
            
            <form (ngSubmit)="contactForm(form.value)" #form="ngForm">
              <fieldset>
                  <div class="row pt-5">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: hidden;">
                           <legend class="text-center" id="titulo-formulario"> ¡Contáctame! </legend>
                    </div>
                  </div>   
                  <div class="row pt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Primer Nommbre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12" id="padding-form">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row pt-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" name="correo" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row pt-3">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="area-texto" rows="3" name="mensaje"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row pt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 20px; width: 100px;">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          
          </div>
        </div>  
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-6" id="columna-derecha"> <img src="assets\img\imagen-contacto.jpg" id="imagen-contacto"> </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

- Servicio:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  sendMessage(body) {
    console.log('**** Servicio ****');
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/formulario', body);
}}
```

- Backend:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const configMensaje = require('./configMensaje');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    console.log('AAPPPPPPPPPPP.JS');
    console.log(req.body.nombre);
    configMensaje(req.body);
    res.status(200).send();
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor corriendo');
});
```

*Captura de la pestaña red:

[image: consola]

- Captura de la consola:

[image: captura de consola]

- Ahora si se ejecuta el método POST pero no se envían los datos, aquí adjunto una captura. Alguna idea?

[image: captura del método POST]

Comment: ¿Se te llega a mostrar el log `console.log('**** Servicio ****');` en la consola?

Comment: Si amigo, si se muestra. Lo coloque precisamente para ver si se estaba ejecutando ese código y si. Es que de hecho el formulario se envía a mi correo pero vació porque no me están llegando los valores de los campos al backend.

Comment: No me cuadra que no se mande nada... puedes poner lo que te sale en consola después de pulsar el submit? ¿Por qué no se ve el texto del botón? has probado a depurar el código poniendo un *breakpoint* en el servicio?

Comment: Listo. Acabo de subir una captura de la consola.

Comment: Es raro: http.post no se ejecuta si no estás suscrito, es *lazy*, pero en tu caso hay una suscripción, no entiendo por qué no se hace la request...

Comment: Tengo casi 2 días tratando dw hacerlo funcionar y buscando información pero no he podido. Ya no se que intentar.

Comment: Puedes crear un escenario en Stackblitz.com?

Comment: Amigo se esta ejecutando el método POST pero no se envía ningún dato, ya no se que cambiar ni que hacer para que funcione. Alguna idea?

Comment: En realidad no estas enviando nada. Estas trabajando con el modo de template-driven forms y a diferencia de reactiveForms necesitas crear un modelo en tu componente y relacionar cada uno de los campos con el ngModel. La linea `(ngSubmit)="contactForm(form.value)"` no tiene sentido puesto que solo estas pasando el `value` del Objeto `ngForm` y no el formulario. Todo lo demás esta bien. Yo te recomiento reactiveForms pero si lo quieres hacer asi aqui te va un ejemplo de como se debe hacer: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/11/angular-6-template-driven-forms-validation-example

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas poner ngModel en cada input, por ejemplo

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Primer Nommbre" ngModel>
```

recuerda tener el FormModule importado en tu AppModule o FeatureModule